# Count multiple values query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use multiple queries to count multiple values and display those values in a table.

```
$resultnieuws = mysql_query("select gamer_int, count(gamer_int) as gamer_count_nieuws     FROM berichten WHERE gamer_int LIKE 'Kenny' AND soort LIKE 'nieuws'");
$resultvideo = mysql_query("select gamer_int, count(gamer_int) as gamer_count_video FROM berichten WHERE gamer_int LIKE 'Kenny' AND soort LIKE 'video'");

echo $resultnieuws['gamer_count_nieuws'];
echo $resultvideo['gamer_count_video'];
```

The echo above gives me no result. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this-

```
    $resultnieuws = mysql_query("select gamer_int, count(gamer_int) as gamer_count_nieuws     FROM berichten WHERE gamer_int LIKE 'Kenny' AND soort LIKE 'nieuws'");
    $resultvideo = mysql_query("select gamer_int, count(gamer_int) as gamer_count_video FROM berichten WHERE gamer_int LIKE 'Kenny' AND soort LIKE 'video'");

    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultnieuws);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultvideo);

    echo $row1['gamer_count_nieuws'];
    echo $row2['gamer_count_video'];
```

Note: mysql_* functions are deprecated, using them not recommended.

Comment: Using them is even **discouraged**.

Comment: This won't work; my edit was declined for some reason, but you can't reference the field from `$row1['gamer_count_nieuws']`, you need to select it from the first row of the result. E.g. `$row1[0]['gamer_count_nieuws']`